# Why wont this Angular Rxjs observer unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to manage memory leak. So one of the things to do is unsubscribe to observers.

I have followed many examples of how to create an observer, and they all work but why can I not unsubscribe from this example?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wsuqoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have spent quite a lot of time on this as it should be so simple.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- you're trying to call `unsubscribe` method on Observable but should be calling it on Subscription instance:

ts

```
controllerSubscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  const controllerObserver = this.getObserverIncrements();
  this.controllerSubscription = controllerObserver.subscribe((nextVal) => {
    this.valueFromSubscriptionNext = nextVal;
  });
}
```

- you don't clear intervals in `unsubscribe` method returned from your Observable

ts

```
const studentsObservable = new Observable(observer => {
  const firstInterval = setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(this.noReasonIncrement);
  }, 8000);

  const secondInterval = setInterval(() => {
    this.noReasonIncrement++;
  }, 1000);
  return {unsubscribe() {
    clearInterval(firstInterval);
    clearInterval(secondInterval);  
  }};
});
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbsbxd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**